# Append multiline html section to the top and bottom of html files

Tags: bash, debian, text-processing, html

what is the most handy way to append multiline html block to the top of html pages in the directory? I have a multiple XHTML files in directory, without a heading part and without closing tags at the bottom. I need append code to the top of every XHTML file (heading part include body tag) and to closing part at the bottom.(`</body></html>`) Not 'find & replace', but append the same html snippets to all files. I tried use XSLT2.0 stylesheet with Gestalt XSLT2.0 command line processor, but it generates many errors, have no documentation, and project has been discontinued.

Comment: So in effect you have the body of the files. How about a simple loop and a 'cat?. `mkdir ../newfiles; for f in * ; do cat top "$f" bottom > "../newfiles/$f" ; done` assuming you have the files top and bottom with the required contents.

Comment: @Gounou No problem. The OP says it works, hopefully they will accept your answer. I will delete my comment and this one as it adds nothing long term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir OutputXHTML

for i in *.xhtml
do
 cat file1 "$i" file3 > OutputXHTML/"$i"
done
```

Comment: Yes, this works as expected and it does its job.